# Swift - open web page in app, button doesn't react

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created a button to make a call from app:

```
   @IBAction func callButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (PhoneNumber != ""){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "telprompt://\(PhoneNumber)")!)
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly fine. Strange thing happens when I want to open a web page. I use nearly exactly same code

```
    @IBAction func openWeb(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)
}
```

But this time button doesn't react and nothing happens. Wherever I was looking for some information about opening web pages in safari from the app, the code was written exactly this way. Do you have any idea where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to add the URL scheme in the second attempt.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

missing url scheme

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 18):

Swift 4, safely unwrapped optional, check if canOpenURL

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Swift 3 Version

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://google.com")! as URL)
```

Comment: if you need a more secure approach, check  before making the openURL call --> UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)

Answer (score 4):

Updated Swift 3.0 version as of iOS 10

```
let googleURL = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")! as URL
UIApplication.shared.open(googleURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2.1, iOS 10 and higher**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://google.com")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```